# Generic Binary Search-java

Tags: java

I am a beginner at Java so I don't really understand this stuff that well and I am currently working on a Java program and found something simliar to the program I am working on.  The only difference from the program the teacher wants is that he wants us to read in a file using `Scanner`. So If you could just show me how to do this one I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks:)

Implement the following method using Binary search.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int binarySearch(E[]list, E key)
```

Comment: And your problem is...

Comment: All the elements need to implement the Comparable interface. That should give you a big hint about how to start.

Comment: Starting this off @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Sorry but you have to try something first. You can take a look at the basic implementation of binary search, which usually is in an array of integers. Then, extrapolate the solution to support generics.

Comment: First, what is a `binarySearch`? Write the pseudo code. What are the initial requirements for the algorithm? What does it do? What are the steps? What does it produce?

Comment: `explain in a way that anyone that does not understand programming can understand`. Don't bring generics into play when you're only at that level.

Comment: My only quandary is why the method is a `void`.

Comment: @user3444609 Do you know how binary search works? If yes, you're stuck with what? If no read on any webpage that explains it.

Comment: Here's a binary search implementation from `java.util.Arrays`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.binarySearch%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%29

Comment: binary search checks the middle element in a list. If element is smaller or bigger it searchs again

Comment: What is that method even supposed to do?  It's void - so how will it give you the thing that it finds?

Comment: For future reference, please [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) before posting about homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step: Create a class which implements `Comparable`.

Second step: Implement the binary search function. You may use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) link.

No matter what you compare, you have to use `implements Comparable`. Than you should override `compareTo` method.

For instance

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
  private int age;
  private String name;
  public Person(String name, int age)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  @Override
  int compareTo(Person p)
  {
     return p.age - this.age;
  }
}

public class BinarySearch {


    private BinarySearch() { }


   public static <E extends Comparable<E>>int binarySearch(E[] list, E key){
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = list.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if      (key < list[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key > list[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
  }

public static void main(String args[])
{
  Person personArray[] = new Person[10];
  Person toBeFound = new Person("Joe", 5);
  // fill the array here
  int x = BinarySearch.binarySearch(personArray, toBeFound);
  if(x == -1) System.out.println("Not found");
  else System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: what about when it asks to add a -1 if not found does that mean I add an else-if statement?

Comment: What do you mean by -1? This is an example of a custom class. If you want to sort integers, than you should use `Integer` class. It is already comparable.

Comment: I really don't think this answers the question, although the link to Wikipedia is useful (especially for those for whom Google is broken).

Comment: @DavidWallace What part do you think is irrelevant?

Comment: The question asks how to implement a binary search.  Your answer says how to do everything EXCEPT implement a binary search.

Comment: Print out each list as supplied and the index value of the item not found(-1 if not) (thats what I meant)

Comment: so i would test it out using for loop?

Comment: @DavidWallace The code can be found anywhere, that's why I skipped the implementation. But I added it now :)

Comment: Oddly the method is `void` - so you can not return anything. Maybe just print something or so.

Comment: @SebastianHöffner I missed that one :) I changed it to `int` now. Or you could just print the messages inside the function instead of `main()`

Comment: @cagirici I think it's not your fault, but the fault of the question, hence "oddly". I would of course also return an `int`.